# principale curvature

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Let $X$ be a differentiable map from a domain $D$ in the plane into $\mathbb{R}^3$

we suppose $X$ is rotationally symmetric ,Orienting so that the axis of rotation is the $y-$plane , we have the standard parametrisation 
$X(\theta,s)=(x(s) cos\theta , y(s) , x(s) sin\theta)$

where $\sigma(s)=(x(s),y(s))$ is the unit speed curvature in the xy-plane and $x(s)\geq 0$ for all $s$.

the principales curvature of $X$ are:

$k_{\sigma}=x^{'}y^{''}-x^{''}y^{'}   $   and   $  k_{\theta}=\dfrac{y^{'}}{x}$

my question is the folowing :
Let  $\vartheta$ be  the angle between the $\sigma^{'}$ and the positive $x-$axis

how can I prouf this $k_{\sigma}=\dfrac{\vartheta(s)-\vartheta(t)}{s-t}$ ?

$\vartheta$ (measured continuously from s=0)

thank you in advance,

Comment: First, you mean that the axis of rotation is the $y$-*axis*. Second, you mean that $k_\sigma = \vartheta'(s)$, or a limit as $t\to s$ of the expression you've written.

Comment: thank you for your interest @Ted Shifrin , but i dont undestand , can you explain to me where is the probléme ?

Comment: When you write the formula with $t$ in it, what is $t$?